# Overlay a figure object to matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, figure

I have a figure object returned by a function.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d, Delaunay
import shapely.geometry
import shapely.ops

points = np.random.random((20, 2))
print(points)
vor = Voronoi(points)
fig = voronoi_plot_2d(vor, show_vertices=True, show_points=True)
fig.add
plt.show()
print(vor.ridge_points)
print(vor.ridge_points[1,0])
print(vor.ridge_points[1,1])
plt.plot(points[vor.ridge_points[1,0]], points[vor.ridge_points[1,1]])
plt.show()
```

I would like to overlay `fig`
on another plot created in the  line
`plt.plot(points[vor.ridge_points[1,0]], points[vor.ridge_points[1,1]])`

Suggestions on how to visualize both the plots in a single figure will be helpful.

Comment: Make an axes and pass the `ax` kwarg to `voronoi_plot_2d`.

Comment: If you leave out the first call to `plt.show()`, then `plt.plot(...)` would default draw further onto the already created plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a `fig, ax` object, and pass the `ax` argument to the `voronoi_plot_2d` as suggested in the comments by @Jody Klymak, like:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d, Delaunay
import shapely.geometry
import shapely.ops
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
points = np.random.random((20, 2))
print(points)
vor = Voronoi(points)
voronoi_plot_2d(vor, show_vertices=True, show_points=True, ax=ax)

print(vor.ridge_points)
print(vor.ridge_points[1,0])
print(vor.ridge_points[1,1])
ax.plot(points[vor.ridge_points[1,0]], points[vor.ridge_points[1,1]])
plt.show()
```

[image]